# Firebase cloud function ends before email is sent

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

Apparently the code below works fine, but the execution of the trigger function ends long before the e-mail is sent.
I don't know if it can lead to errors.

What would be the correct way to delay the end until the e-mail is sent ?

```
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
        user: "email",
        pass: "pass"
      }
});

exports.createEnrollment = functions.firestore
    .document("enrollments/{enrollmentId}")
    .onCreate(event => {

        var newValue = event.data.data();

        // ... other commands to retrieve email content and recipient

         mailTransport
          .sendMail(content)
          .then(() => {
            console.log(`New email sent to ${email}`);
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
          });

     console.log("ending function");
     return event.data.data();

});
```

Comment: are the `console.logs` appearing ?

Comment: They appear in cloud functions log. But the logs also inform when a functions end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning before your promise resolves.

```
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  auth: {
    user: "email",
    pass: "pass"
  }
});

exports.createEnrollment = functions.firestore
  .document("enrollments/{enrollmentId}")
  .onCreate(event => {

    var newValue = event.data.data();    

    // ... other commands to retrieve email content and recipient

    return mailTransport
      .sendMail(content)
      .then(() => {
        console.log(`New email sent to ${email}`);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
      });
    console.log("ending function");
  });
```

mailtransport.sendMail is a promise which should be returned.

But now you will never see ending function in your log.. If you want to. Move it within your .then function, or chain another one.

Comment: But, as it is a firestore trigger, I think it should return a value or a promise that modify the original value. Isn't it ?

Comment: You return a promise that's resolved only after *all* the async work in the function is complete.  It doesn't matter what the work is, but the promise has to represent all of it.